# Scientific image display python

Tags: python, image, image-processing, scipy

Is there a full feature image display lib for python?
With the ability to identify pixel values, plot profiles, adjust brightness/contrast etc 
- something like [ImageJ](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/features.html)

[PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/), [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/), [scipy-skimage](http://scikits-image.org/) all do little more than put up a bitmap in a TK window.
I can't get opencv to use the new Qt highgui window in python.

Any suggestions?

ps. And it has work on Windows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using skimage 0.5:

```
from skimage import io, data
io.use_plugin('qt')
io.imshow(data.camera(), fancy=True)
```

There's a recent discussion on the skimage mailing list at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scikits-image/LgV9D4Cp5d0.

Answer (score 1):

Matplotlib's plots actually have some nice [event handler](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/event_handling.html) capabilities which make it very easy to extend a view with additional mouse-keyboard driven functionality (very conveniently, events are reported with both view and data coordinates).  I've certainly used it to add mouse-drag driven contrast-brightness adjustment to a displayed image, and to launch algorithms needing an initial seedpoint.

Answer (score 0):

The [gimp](http://www.gimp.org/) has a [python scripting expansion](http://www.gimp.org/docs/python/index.html).

Comment: That's more to script gimp functions from python - I need an interactive display for scipy sessions

Comment: Maybe you should expand on what goes wrong if you try to use the Qt highgui window, assuming that meets your needs?

Comment: it doesn't have any of the new highgui features (or I'm missing something). In python it's just the regular old bitmap display